# How to Use Matlab to Analyze and Graph CO2 Emissions Data

Tags: matlab

For a project, I have to analyze CO2 data over the past 30 years or so and correlate it to temperature increase using MATLAB. Since I am still very new to MATLAB, I am having trouble importing this data to Matlab, getting Matlab to recognize this data, and plotting it as line/bar graphs. I would appreciate it if someone could walk me through this as I recently started learning MATLAB. My data set can be found [here](ftp://aftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/products/trends/co2/co2_annmean_gl.txt).

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, the easiest way would be to paste the data in and look at the help for plot, by typing `help plot` at the Command Line.

```
data=[1980   338.80     0.10
  1981   339.99     0.10
  1982   340.76     0.10];
figure
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2))
ylabel('CO_2 (ppm)')
xlabel('Year')
```